# Usage of preposition «of» in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

When should I use the preposition *of* and when can I omit it?

Let say, I have the following pair of sentences:

> *Development of the high quality software…*
>   *Development the high quality software…*

Are these both sentences correct?
Are they equal?
Which one of them is better from the stylistic point of view?

Is there any difference between the rules when we're talking about the complete sentence or just short statement? For instance:

> *Development of the high quality software is a critical for the company.*   (Responsibility:) *Development the high quality software*

Another similar cases:

> *Learning the new language*
>   *Learning of the new language*

Comment: This question will get better and more helpful answers on our sister site, [ELL.se], so I've voted to move it there.  FWIW, your second example sentence, the one which omits *of*, is ungrammatical.

Comment: Most of your examples aren't "sentences" - they're just ***compound noun phrases***. If the "head noun" of the np is a *gerund* (an *-ing* verb form, such as *developing, learning*) that verb may be immediately followed by an "object" with no intervening preposition. But you can't do that with ordinary nouns, so *development the high quality software* is syntactically invalid.

Comment: 'other similar sentences:' not so. Look up 'Gerund and present participle phrases'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Development of the high quality software…
>
> Development the high quality software…

Neither is correct, sorry. There are several issues:

- "of" is required – I'll explain why below
- "software" is a mass noun, not a countable noun, so "the" (or "a") is incorrect
- "critical" is not a noun, so "a critical" is incorrect

---

To understand why "of" is needed, let's look at a slightly different version of the sentence:

> Developing high quality software is critical for the company.

In this version, "of" is *not* needed. "Developing" is the verb, and "software" is the object. So far so good.

What happens when we change "developing" to "development"? Well, "-ment" is a suffix that *turns a verb into a noun*. When you add "-ment" to a verb, the resulting noun can have a couple of different meanings:

1. The condition brought on by the verb – *enjoyment*
2. The result of the verb – *accomplishment*
3. The process or action of the verb – *management*

"Development" uses meaning #3 – "development" is "the process of developing".

But because "development" is now a noun, we need "of" to indicate *what is being developed* – because a noun doesn't take an object in the way that a verb can.

---

> Is there any difference between the rules when we're talking about the complete sentence or just short statement?

No, there's no difference. Although the "short statement" is probably not grammatical on its own; those are called "sentence fragments" and they are a grammatical error (and a larger topic).

Comment: +1 All great apart from your last sentence. Sentence fragments aren't 'ungrammatical' - they're just not whole sentences. That's why we see them all the time used as headings and titles. Your post would be soooo much better without that last sentence!!